# Falta tradução em mensagem ao ganhar privilégio de criar uma salas de bate-papo

Tags: bug, tradução, internacionalização

Ao ganhar o privilégio de criar salas de bate-papo percebi que falta tradução na mensagem, segue:

[image: falta tradução]

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege – create chat rooms – learn more

Imagino que deveria ser algo como:

> Parabéns, você ganhou um privilégio - criar salas de bate-papo - saiba mais